# Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.showOpps

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

I want to Render a section of my Visualforce page only if I found Opportunities related to the Account I'm working with and I'm getting this error message.
I have a VF Page and a controller extension.

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="MyControllerExtension" action="{!init}">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock TITLE="Company" id="theBlock">
            <apex:outputText value="Have you created a new opportunity "/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
               <!-- <apex:selectRadio value="{!BooleanOptions}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!yesNo}"/>
                </apex:selectRadio > -->
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Opportunities related to this Account" rendered="{!hasOpp}">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!showOpps}" var="opp" width="500">
                <apex:column headervalue="Opportunity Name" value="{!opp.Name}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Closed Date" value="{!opp.CloseDate}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity Stage"  value="{!opp.StageName}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}" rendered="false" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.MasterId__c}" rendered="false" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.CDS_Company_ID__c}" rendered="false" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.OwnerId}" rendered="false" />
</apex:page>
```

This is the controller ext:

```
public with sharing class MyControllerExtension {
    private final Account acct;

    public MyControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account) stdController.getRecord();
    }

    /*public List<SelectOption> getYesNo() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('true', 'Yes'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('false', 'No'));
        return options;
    } */

    public boolean hasOpp {
       get {
           List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Account.Id = :acct.Id]);
           return (oppList.IsEmpty());
       }
        private set;
    }

    public List<Opportunity> showOpps() {
        List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();

        if (acct.Id != null){
            oppList = [SELECT Name, Amount, CloseDate, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Account.Id =: acct.Id ];
            return oppList;
        } else {
            oppList = null;
            return oppList;
        }
    }

    public PageReference init() {
        String CompanyId = acct_Company_ID__c;
        if (String.isEmpty(CompanyId)) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'The new account setup process is not yet available for this company. Please try again in a few minutes.'));
            return null;
        }

        System.debug('salesforceId:' + acct.Id);

        // Get "Landing Page" where user will be taken to open or check existing account.
        PageReference page = new PageReference(EnvironmentSettings.getOpenAccountUrl());
              page.getParameters().put('salesForceId', acct.Id);

        page.setRedirect(true);
        return page;
    }

}
```

The error is thrown on this line in my VF Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection Title="Opportunities related to this Company" rendered="{!hasOpp}">
```

Even though I have a get and set on hasOpp (in my ext controller), not sure what I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Error is with showOpps, its must be getShowOpps() in controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line of markup that is actually throwing your error is one further down:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!showOpps}" ...>
```

The reason is that you declared `showOpps` as a method, not a property.

**Method Syntax**

```
public List<Opportunity> showOpps()
{
    // cannot reference showOpps as a property
}
```

**Property Syntax**

```
public List<Opportunity> getShowOpps()
{
    // can reference showOpps as a property
}
```

**Getter Syntax**

```
public List<Opportunity> showOpps
{
    get
    {
        // can reference showOpps as a property
    }

    private set;
    // having any setter is optional
    // use the private access modifier if you do declare one
    // there's no good reason to leave it public
}
```